# Can't specify JWKSet URL when validating confidential token coming from Azure AD

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, nimbus-jose-jwt

Connecting to Azure AD v2.0 endpoint I cannot validate my token which jwt.io and jwt.ms declare as valid

A public token is no problem:

```
IDTokenValidator validator = new IDTokenValidator(issuer, clientId, JWSAlgorithm.RS256, jwkSetUrl);     
IDTokenClaimsSet validatedClaimsSet;
try {
    validatedClaimsSet = validator.validate(jwt, null);
} catch (BadJOSEException | JOSEException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    return;
}
```

but validating a token coming from a confidential client will throw the exception

```
Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
```

with the following code

```
IDTokenValidator validator = new IDTokenValidator(issuer, clientId, JWSAlgorithm.RS256, new Secret(authMethod.getSecret()));
```

No matching keys are found because (JWKMatcher.java:1258)

- keytype does not match: OCT instead of RSA
- use is null
- ops is null

[image]

It seems an inadequate JWKSet is created from the secret in ImmutableSecret.java:47 but I seem to lack understanding as to how the secret can contain the necessary data found in the jwks_uri from Azure

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: The error says *Another algorithm expected*, but you have hardcoded `JWSAlgorithm.RS256`in your validator. What algorithm is set in the header of that token?

Comment: True, it shouldn't be hard-coded but header alg is RS256

Answer (score 0):

Validating an ID token works the same way for both public and confidential clients. So just get rid of the secret parameter and your code will work - using the token's signing public key.

The secret parameter is for JWTs that are signed with a symmetric algorithm such as HMACSHA256 - which is almost never a good idea. More about this topic in [JWT Security Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/).